# React hooks prevState error: "Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons..."

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React hooks, trying to set a state, while also using prevState:

```
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState("");

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setInputs((prevState) => e.target.value);
  };

return (

            <input
              onChange={changeHandler}
              type="text"
              id="title"
            />
```

The prevState isn't necessary but its presence is what causing the error after typing more than one character in the input field. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the event asynchronously, but as the error says, the event object is reused.

Don't access the event asynchronously. Instead, extract the value you need synchronously.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setInputs(prevState => value);
};
```

Using the callback of `setInputs` doesn't do anything here though. You'd need to use a callback only if you previously updated the state before `changeHandler` was called, *and before* a re-render. You'd also need to use a callback only if you need to factor in the previous state into the new state. For example, if you did something like

```
onChange={(e) => { doSomethingThatChangesState(e); changeHandler(e); }}
```

and if the state was an object with multiple values:

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  // update the `value` property in state:
  setInputs(prevState => ({...prevState, value }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a slightly older version of React, pre-17, that uses an event pool. Event objects are nullified and returned to the event pool ***before*** the enqueued state update is processed asynchronously.

It's not an issue with the non-functional state update because you access the event object synchronously, passing the current value to the state updater.

If you need the event value for a functional state update then save a copy of it in callback scope.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setInputs((prevState) => {
    // reference value here safely
  });
};
```

Comment: You're totally right it's an older version now I understand thank you very much!